# Безалаберный: без — чего?

Tags: этимология

Безалаберный — значит безответственный, несобранный. А что тут за корень? Без чего, собственно, этот человек?

Answer (score 1):

Найдём в словаре Даля это слово:

> Безалаберный, **безалаборный**, бестолковый, беспорядочный, неурядливый, взбалмошный, сбреховатый, неразумный, шальной;

Как видно, оно могло выглядеть немного по-разному. Отбросив явные приставку "без-", вставку (суффикс) "н" и окончание, поищем в том же источнике производящую основу "алабор":

> АЛАБОР м. (мадьярск. тормоз; не чудское ли или турецкое слово?) стар., а местами (твер.) и ныне: устройство, распорядок, порядок;

Такое толкование вполне укладывается в смысл слова: "без алабера/алабора" — значит "без порядка", отсюда и "безалаберный" — "беспорядочный".

Фасмер и Шанский придерживаются такой версии.

Comment: Для оформления цитаты достаточно одного знака >. Я бы и сам исправил, да уж очень маленькая правка получается - система не пропускает.